# Replacement of English numbers of a string with Arabic numbers

Tags: java, regex

I'm going to find number chars in a String and replace them with their Arabic versions.
The Code is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String pattern = "[0-9]+";
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    String mainText = "34titi685dytti5685fjjfj8585443";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(mainText);

    int i = 0;

    while (m.find()) {

        System.out.println("Match number " + i);
        String tmp = m.group();
        char[] cTmp = tmp.toCharArray();
        for (int j = 0; j < cTmp.length; j++) {
            cTmp[j] = (char) ((int) cTmp[j] + 1584);
        }

        m.group().replaceFirst(tmp,new String(cTmp));
        i++;
    }
    System.out.println(mainText);
}
```

But at the end it prints the same string `mainText`.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Out of curiosity's sake: What are English numbers vs. Arabic numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not how you do a replacement using `Matcher`. `m.group()` just gives you the matched part of the string. Whatever replacement you do in it, you have to perform concatenation with original string. This is due to the fact that `String`s are immutable objects. You don't perform in-place replacement to it.

The proper way to do this is to create a [`StringBuffer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) object, and use [`Matcher#appendReplacement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement%28java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.lang.String%29) and [`Matcher#appendTail`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendTail%28java.lang.StringBuffer%29) methods.

You do it like this:

```
StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

while (m.find()) {

    String tmp = m.group();
    char[] cTmp = tmp.toCharArray();

    for (int j = 0; j < cTmp.length; j++) {
        cTmp[j] = (char) (cTmp[j] + 1584);  // You don't need to typecast `cTmp[j]` to `int`.
    }

    m.appendReplacement(buffer, new String(cTmp));

}

m.appendTail(buffer);

System.out.println(buffer.toString());
```

Comment: maybe you should add, that strings are immutable objects, so he cant replace it in the original object

Answer (score 2):

String is final and immutable, you have to assign the new string to itself.

Comment: It would be good to include a sample line in this answer that shows the kind of assignment the OP needs to make.

Answer (score 0):

use `StringBuilder` to append the values every time.

```
StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
//
//
 m.group().replaceFirst(stringBuilder,new String(cTmp));
```

instead of

```
m.group().replaceFirst(tmp,new String(cTmp));
```

Assign the outcoming value to the mainText

Comment: @RohitJain yes you correct it only shows the last replaceed value

Comment: I just need to replace numbers not whole string

Comment: @SuperHornet I suggest you to use StringBuffer to append the values, like the Rohit Jan did